# publish tableau workbook (twb or twbx) without tableau desktop

Tags: http, tableau-api

Has anybody found a way to spoof the requests that tableau desktop makes when publishing a report? I obviously know that they do not provide an API, but it seems like it should be pretty straightforward to just authenticate, and then POST the workbook. Has anybody found a way to do this? I publish a few workbooks very regularly (with minor changes that I can make using sed/awk) and I would like to set up a script to automate the process.

Answer (score 6):

No need to reverse-engineer the POST - you can use the `TabCmd.exe` console app to publish the workbook to Server:

```
tabcmd.exe login -u username -p password -s http://serverlocation
tabcmd.exe publish -n "c:\path\to\SomeWorkbook.twbx"
```

Batch this puppy up and you have an easy way to publish.

BTW, if you don't have `TabCmd` on your box, copy it from the `\bin` folder of server, along with the following support files:

```
boost_signals_vc100-mt-1_45.dll
iconv.dll
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

Comment: This is a great answer, except I need something that can work cross-platform. :(

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're stuck then, sorry. If it makes you feel any better the Tableau devs know that a true web service really needs to be created to do this sort of stuff. You won't see it in 7, but who knows about the next version.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a wcf service and host in tableau server as a windows service.
write some opretation contract which can execute tabcmd commands in server.
from outside you can call operations to publish reports.