# How to publish to Tableau Public without using Tableau Desktop

Tags: api, post, tableau-api, publish

I am currently generating a .tde using the Tableau Python API. This .tde should be generated with new data daily, but as of right now I cannot find a way to publish to Tableau Public without going through Tableau Desktop.

Is there a way to publish to Tableau Public without going through the desktop client? Perhaps by spoofing a POST, through some use of tabcmd.exe, or something else?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065411/publish-tableau-workbook-twb-or-twbx-without-tableau-desktop) asked something along the same lines, but was met with an answer which is specific to Tableau Server, which is a separate product which I do not have access to.

Comment: Are you able to publish via Tableau Desktop? If so, can't you use the commandline interface to Tableau to script a publish operation?

Comment: This is an old problem I had, but I was able to publish via Tableau Desktop. If I remember correctly, the commandline interface to Tableau (TabCMD.exe) was only available if you had Tableau Server, which I did not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [publish tableau workbook (twb or twbx) without tableau desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065411/publish-tableau-workbook-twb-or-twbx-without-tableau-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to publish to a server, Public or otherwise, without authenticating.

Tableau Public handles authentication by way of the account login prompt you get from their paid or free Desktop application.

After connecting your workbook to the .tde you have generated you can save the workbook.

[image]

And then proceed to authenticate your account and publish your work.

[image]

No need to buy anything as you can use Tableau Public for free. You can download trials of both Tableau Online and Tableau Server to test the code you would like to use to publish your .tdes outside of Tableau Public.